# Problems serializing types for a .NET WCF Service: Service WSDL defines empty types in XSD

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, serialization

I am writing a web service using WCF.

1. I created data contracts.
2. I created my service contract (interface). I defined methods (whose parameters are typed as for the data contracts).
3. I implemented the service contract creating a service class.
4. I hosted my service using a svc file and IIS.
5. I tried my service, looked for http://localhost/myvirtdiriis/myservice.svc --> The service was loaded, and a nice web page describing the presence of my service showed.
6. I wanted to look at the WSDL. Using the provided link I can see that types are only defined, I can see just the types definition (like `<complexType>`), but nothing inside (types are empty).
7. I coded a simple client, a call to an operation went good, but when returning the type it is empty (internal fields have the construction values, while my service place some values there), for example, a call to an operation returning a type having three strings set by the operation contract method to "Hello", "Hello2" and "Hello3", returns the type having these strings set to `""` (construction values, as if no changes happened).

What happened?

It seems that serialization fails.

I am providing some:

A1) A part of the service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/")]
   public interface IOCXSService {
      [OperationContract(Action = "http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/Browse")]
      BrowseResponse Browse(BrowseRequest request);
      ...
}
```

A2) The service implementation:

```
public class MyService : IOCXSService {
      ...
      public BrowseResponse Browse(BrowseRequest request) {
         ...
      }
      ...
   }
```

B) Types:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/", Name = "BrowseResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "BrowseResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/", IsWrapped = true)]
    public class BrowseResponse {

        [DataMember(Name = "BrowseResult", Order = 0)]
        public OCXS.OCXSServiceLibrary.OPCXMLDA10.ReplyBase BrowseResult;

        [DataMember(Name = "Elements", Order = 1)]
        public BrowseElement[] Elements;

        [DataMember(Name = "Errors", Order = 2)]
        public OPCError[] Errors;

        [DataMember(Name = "ContinuationPoint", Order = 3)]
        public string ContinuationPoint;

        [DataMember(Name = "MoreElements", Order = 4)]
        public bool MoreElements;

        public BrowseResponse() {
        }

        public BrowseResponse(OCXS.OCXSServiceLibrary.OPCXMLDA10.ReplyBase BrowseResult, BrowseElement[] Elements, OPCError[] Errors, string ContinuationPoint, bool MoreElements) {
            this.BrowseResult = BrowseResult;
            this.Elements = Elements;
            this.Errors = Errors;
            this.ContinuationPoint = ContinuationPoint;
            this.MoreElements = MoreElements;
        }

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/", Name = "ReplyBase")]
    public class ReplyBase : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private System.DateTime rcvTimeField;

        private System.DateTime replyTimeField;

        private string clientRequestHandleField;

        private string revisedLocaleIDField;

        private serverState serverStateField;

        [DataMember(Name = "RcvTime", Order = 0)]
        public System.DateTime RcvTime {
            get {
                return this.rcvTimeField;
            }
            set {
                this.rcvTimeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("RcvTime");
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "ReplyTime", Order = 1)]
        public System.DateTime ReplyTime {
            get {
                return this.replyTimeField;
            }
            set {
                this.replyTimeField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ReplyTime");
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "ClientRequestHandle", Order = 2)]
        public string ClientRequestHandle {
            get {
                return this.clientRequestHandleField;
            }
            set {
                this.clientRequestHandleField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ClientRequestHandle");
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "RevisedLocaleID", Order = 3)]
        public string RevisedLocaleID {
            get {
                return this.revisedLocaleIDField;
            }
            set {
                this.revisedLocaleIDField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("RevisedLocaleID");
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "ServerState", Order = 4)]
        public serverState ServerState {
            get {
                return this.serverStateField;
            }
            set {
                this.serverStateField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ServerState");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/", Name = "BrowseElement")]
    public class BrowseElement : INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private ItemProperty[] propertiesField;

        private string nameField;

        private string itemPathField;

        private string itemNameField;

        private bool isItemField;

        private bool hasChildrenField;

        [DataMember(Name = "Properties", Order = 0)]
        public ItemProperty[] Properties {
            get {
                return this.propertiesField;
            }
            set {
                this.propertiesField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Properties");
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "Name", Order = 1)]
        public string Name {
            get {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set {
                this.nameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "ItemPath", Order = 2)]
        public string ItemPath {
            get {
                return this.itemPathField;
            }
            set {
                this.itemPathField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ItemPath");
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "ItemName", Order = 3)]
        public string ItemName {
            get {
                return this.itemNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.itemNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ItemName");
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "IsItem", Order = 4)]
        public bool IsItem {
            get {
                return this.isItemField;
            }
            set {
                this.isItemField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsItem");
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "HasChildren", Order = 5)]
        public bool HasChildren {
            get {
                return this.hasChildrenField;
            }
            set {
                this.hasChildrenField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("HasChildren");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/", Name = "OPCError")]
    public class OPCError : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string textField;

        private System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName idField;

        [DataMember(Name = "Text", Order = 0)]
        public string Text {
            get {
                return this.textField;
            }
            set {
                this.textField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "ID", Order = 1)]
        public System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName ID {
            get {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set {
                this.idField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

C) WSDL (a part, the one concerning type definitions)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/" targetNamespace="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="Browse">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="BrowseResponse">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="GetProperties">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="GetPropertiesResponse">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="GetStatus">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="GetStatusResponse">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="Read">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="ReadResponse">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="Subscribe">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="SubscribeResponse">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="SubscriptionCancel">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="SubscriptionCancelResponse">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="SubscriptionPolledRefresh">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="SubscriptionPolledRefreshResponse">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name="Write">-<xs:complexType><xs:sequence/></xs:complexType></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="WriteResponse">
         <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The piece above is included here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/Imports">
<xsd:import namespace="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/" schemaLocation="http://localhost/OCXS/OCXS.svc?xsd=xsd0"/></xsd:schema></wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="BrowseRequest"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Browse"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="BrowseResponse"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:BrowseResponse"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetPropertiesRequest"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetProperties"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetPropertiesResponse"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPropertiesResponse"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetStatusRequest"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetStatus"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetStatusResponse"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetStatusResponse"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ReadRequest"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Read"/></wsdl:message>-<wsdl:message name="ReadResponse"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ReadResponse"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SubscribeRequest"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Subscribe"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SubscribeResponse"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubscribeResponse"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SubscriptionCancelRequest"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubscriptionCancel"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="SubscriptionCancelResponse"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubscriptionCancelResponse"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SubscriptionPolledRefreshRequest"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubscriptionPolledRefresh"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SubscriptionPolledRefreshResponse"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubscriptionPolledRefreshResponse"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="WriteRequest"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Write"/></wsdl:message>-<wsdl:message name="WriteResponse"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:WriteResponse"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IOCXSService">-<wsdl:operation name="Browse"><wsdl:input name="BrowseRequest" message="tns:BrowseRequest" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/Browse"/><wsdl:output name="BrowseResponse" message="tns:BrowseResponse" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/IOCXSService/BrowseResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetProperties"><wsdl:input name="GetPropertiesRequest" message="tns:GetPropertiesRequest" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/GetProperties"/><wsdl:output name="GetPropertiesResponse" message="tns:GetPropertiesResponse" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/IOCXSService/GetPropertiesResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="GetStatus"><wsdl:input name="GetStatusRequest" message="tns:GetStatusRequest" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/GetStatus"/><wsdl:output name="GetStatusResponse" message="tns:GetStatusResponse" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/IOCXSService/GetStatusResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Read"><wsdl:input name="ReadRequest" message="tns:ReadRequest" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/Read"/><wsdl:output name="ReadResponse" message="tns:ReadResponse" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/IOCXSService/ReadResponse"/></wsdl:operation>-<wsdl:operation name="Subscribe"><wsdl:input name="SubscribeRequest" message="tns:SubscribeRequest" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/Subscribe"/><wsdl:output name="SubscribeResponse" message="tns:SubscribeResponse" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/IOCXSService/SubscribeResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="SubscriptionCancel"><wsdl:input name="SubscriptionCancelRequest" message="tns:SubscriptionCancelRequest" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/SubscriptionCancel"/><wsdl:output name="SubscriptionCancelResponse" message="tns:SubscriptionCancelResponse" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/IOCXSService/SubscriptionCancelResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="SubscriptionPolledRefresh"><wsdl:input name="SubscriptionPolledRefreshRequest" message="tns:SubscriptionPolledRefreshRequest" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/SubscriptionPolledRefresh"/><wsdl:output name="SubscriptionPolledRefreshResponse" message="tns:SubscriptionPolledRefreshResponse" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/IOCXSService/SubscriptionPolledRefreshResponse"/></wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Write"><wsdl:input name="WriteRequest" message="tns:WriteRequest" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/Write"/><wsdl:output name="WriteResponse" message="tns:WriteResponse" wsaw:Action="http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/IOCXSService/WriteResponse"/></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType></wsdl:definitions>
```

NOTE:
If I remove the `MessageContract` attribute from `BrowseResponse` and `BrowseRequest` (both removed otherwose the runtime gets crazy), the problem persists....
Is it really an issue concerning messagecontracts???

**MAYBE THE SOLUTION**

OK everybody, maybe I can see the light...
If I remove all `DataContract`(s) and `ServiceContract`(s) attributes namespace and names (always without `MessageContract`(s)), everything works. Well, I get wsdl and types, but t worked even with them (but always without `MessageContract`(s)).
Here's why (I would like to get confirm from you):

The namespace I specified: http://opcfoundation.org/webservices/XMLDA/1.0/ is not a simple name, well, here you can find WSDL definitions for my operations and types (already defined). My svc does not generate complete WSDL definitions with types BECAUSE IT ALREADY HAS THEM defined in that namespace I provided!!!

What do you think about this?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the DataContract?  Does it contain Datamember attributes?

Comment: Then please post the C# and WSDL of one item.

Comment: Is there another section about BrowseResponse in the WSDL?

Comment: Only the one I posted right now... sorry for the indentation...

Comment: However, havve you a general idea about what is happening??? Is it something concering namespaces??? or what???

Comment: No, I had to refresh my meory a little but the details of a DataContract are not spelled out in WSDL, no obvious error there.

Comment: WCF has some quite usable debugging tools (looking at messages etc), time to break them out. But start with debugging your C# server side , is the data really being filled?

Comment: @Henk Interesting question.... It seems no... in the method I showed you, the Browse action, I create a BrowseResponse instance and return it. Before returning it, I fill it with some values, but when I call my service from my client, those values are null...

Comment: About the namespaces: You should use your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined the class BrowseResponse as a `[MessageContract]`, in addition to `[DataContract]`. Based on what you're saying, it seems like [MessageContract] takes precedence (which makes sense - [MC] defines the SOAP envelope for the message, which can contain *members*, and those members can be data contracts. Members of message contracts are defined with either `[MessageHeader]` or `[MessageBodyMember]` attributes, and since you don't have any, the contract is essentially empty.

You didn't show the definition of BrowseRequest, but since you're using a [MC] type in the request, you also need to use a [MC] in the response, so I'm assuming it has the same problem.

Comment: OK... let me try to fix it... I'll tell you the result... One question please... What does really do MessageContract??? What relationship there is with DataContract?

Comment: MessageContract isn't something widely used. You'd normally use it when you want some parts of the request/response to go in the SOAP body, and some parts to go in the SOAP header (usually required for interoperability with existing services) - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx for more information.

Comment: Data contracts are used for defining the data which is to be exchanged between the client and the server. Members in a message contract can be of data contract types (the opposite is not true). So message contracts are used for defining the message *shape*, while data contracts are used to define the message *content*. This is the general view, intended mostly for guidance - one can use attributes in data contracts to define "shape" (order of elements), and fields in message contract to define content as well.

Comment: I removed MessageCOntractAttributes,,,, now I can0t see anything in my wsdl file... no types, no messages, nothing... :( If I place back those attributes, nothing changes (I assure you that I restart IIS and refresh my service host)

Comment: On thing you can try to do is to start again from an empty service, then add only 1 operation (i.e., Browse), and define BrowseRequest and BrowseResponse with one member each. Then browse to the ?wsdl page. If this works (i.e., you see the messages, types), then start adding them back, until you hit a point where it stops working.

Comment: @carlosfigueira I thought so too, just wanted to avoid it :) However, got no better solutions... I'll try..

Comment: @carlosfigueira Thanks anyway carlos, your advice was correct, despite all things I was able to notice, the final consideration, that is the error I made, was not applying message contract attributes to members in order to place them in body or header, for this reason I did not receive any content in my message replies. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very old thread but maybe this helps someone.

Our client had a .NET 2.0 application and we created a .NET 4 WCF project. There were some C# classes that represent complex types. When the client application added WebReference and sent across the data we found some properties **weren't** serializing e.g. decimals, eventually we had to change the Serializer from the default serializer to XmlSerializerFormat which allowed us to serialize classes with regular XML Serializer and not the WCF DataContractSerializer.

This article was very helpful from MSDN
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901(v=vs.110).aspx

See example below, we used no WCF contract attributes to allow for the interaction with Webservices.

```
<ServiceContract()>
<XmlSerializerFormat()>
Public Interface IService    
    <OperationContract()>
    <WebMethod()>
    Function CreateLoan(ByVal LoanRequest As LoanAccount) As String
End Interface

//C# Class
public class LoanAccount
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string New { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public String CustomerNo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string AcctType { get; set; }
}
```