# Python Soap Client calls WCF endpoint and return list of object without showing class name

Tags: python, c#, wcf, soap

New to WCF and felt confused about data member and how it serialize to JSON.

In Python Script, I call WCF via `zeep`

```
from zeep import Client

client = Client('xxxxx.asmx?WSDL')
result = client.service.GetPromoteRequests()
```

The result looks like this

```
{
    "PromoteRequests": {
        "PromoteRequest": [
            {
                "Id":: 1,
                "Name": "123",
            },
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Name": "456",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But I want to hide the key name `PromoteRequest`, which is from my WCF class name.
Like

```
{
    "PromoteRequests": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "123",
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "456",
        }
    ]
}
```

In WCF, I define the response class like this.

```
[DataContract]
public class GetPromoteRequestsResponse {
    [DataMember]
    public List<PromoteRequest> PromoteRequests { get; set; }
}

public class PromoteRequestDependency {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You can refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257703/problems-serializing-types-for-a-net-wcf-service-service-wsdl-defines-empty-ty

Comment: @TheobaldDu I don't think it's revelent.

Comment: Try to add [IgnoreDataMember] attribute.